# jabref web search stopped working

Tags: windows, jabref, research

I've been using Jabref for a few months, I really like it; but suddenly the web search function doesn't work.  Regardless of what search term I type in for Medline, I get a "no references found" message.  I'm running the latest version on a Windows 7 Professional computer at my office.  I made a firewall exception for Jabref.  Any other troubleshooting suggestions?

Note - web search doesn't work for any of the other engines, either - I get an error message, or the search box closes without showing any results.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.